# SparkSQL: not found value expr

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, apache-spark-sql

I'm having some problems in building a simple application with Spark SQL. What I want to do is to add a new column to a `DataFrame`. Thus, I have done:

```
val sqlContext=new HiveContext(sc)
import sqlContext._
// creating the DataFrame
correctDF.withColumn("COL1", expr("concat('000',COL1)") )
```

but when I build it with sbt it throws the exception:

```
not found: value expr
```

(and also Eclipse complains about it)

Instead in the `spark-shell` it works like a charm.

In my build.sbt file I have:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.6.0" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.6.0" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.10" % "1.6.0" % "provided"
```

I've added the last line after I read a post, but nothing changed...

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found the answer. I was missing this import:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```